# Can a non-generic struct implement a generic function in rust?

Tags: generics, syntax, rust

Can a non-generic struct implement a generic function in rust, which works like:

```rust
struct S;

impl <T> S {
    fn do_something(value : T) {
        //do something
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = /*a value*/;
    S::do_something(a);
}
```

If not, assuming S implement a generic trait Tt:

```rust
struct S;

impl <T> Tt<T> for S {
    fn a_func(value : T) {
        //do something
    }
}

impl <T> S {
    fn do_something(value : T) {
        //do something
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = /*a value*/;
    S::do_something(a);
}
```

Is there any way to make it works?

Comment: how about defining generic parameter for `fn` instead of `struct` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only declare a type variable for an `impl` block if it is used in the type itself.

However, you can introduce new type variables on individual methods too:

```
impl S {
    fn do_something<T>(value: T) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

This is particularly common for arguments that are closures, because every closure has a different type, so this is necessary for you to be able to call the method with a different closure each time. For example, [`Iterator::map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.map) is defined like this:

```
fn map<B, F>(self, f: F) -> Map<Self, F>
where
    F: FnMut(Self::Item) -> B,
```

If the `F` was declared for the type instead of the method then you would have to use the same closure every time you call `map` - not very useful.